# Problem while moving avd to another location

Tags: android, move, android-virtual-device

I want to move avd file to another location:

```
android move avd -n titanium_6_HVGA1 -p c:\avd
```

but I get as a result help for java:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
       (to execute a class)
```

etc...
Oh, I just checked, I could run

```
android list
```

without any problem, but now I am getting the same as for "android move.." command

Can someone please help me?

Deveti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling jdk and android solved problem.